# Rails - Image_tag alternative image

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Whats the best way to create an image_tag(via the rails helper) that displays another image if the default one is broken instead of text. It doesn't have to support recursion. I just have a default image I want to use if a link is broken.

Comment: There's a neat way to do this if you're using Carrierwave to upload photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via JS, here shown as jQuery:

```
$('img').error(function() {
  $(this).attr('src', 'missing.png');
});
```

If it's a specific image you could attach the error handler to just that object.

I don't know of any way to do this via the `image_tag` helper; you'd have to make a request from the app to the src URL and check for an error. I'd make sure that's actually what you *need* to do before going down that road, though, but it depends on your requirements.

Comment: This looks like the cleanest way for what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: @Helsing I wouldn't discount the CSS idea, although I've never tried it with any real success.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772346/display-alternate-image) uses the `background-image` CSS property to point to a default image, which would be used if your image isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with similar kind of problem where I have inside table several thumbnail pictures and I needed to checked if that picture is missing then show default image.

For this I use image_tag with helper method. In helper method I check with File.exist? if file exist. If it was then I returned path to image as a string to image_tag else I returned path to default image.