# show alternate image if img src is not found - knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have this piece of code.

```
<img data-bind="attr: {src: 'imagePath'}, style: { 'background-image': 'url('imagePath')' }" class="img-responsive">
```

The problem is it is showing two images. One is the image coming from `src` and other one coming from `background` image. My goal was to enable the `background` image when the `src` image is not available.

Comment: Why don't you only use the `src` attribute, and wire it to an observable that will resolve the image source when it becomes available?

Comment: Default to showing the fallback image, and replace it if and when the other image is found.

Comment: Using a background image as the alternate will create some problems, e.g., it will still display a broken image icon and you will need to set the height and width. That is why using only the src seems a better solution.

Comment: Just wondering if my answer did, in fact, answer your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you can do is create a custom binding, let's call it `safeSrc`.

In this binding, you listen to the `load` and `error` events of your image - rendering your image if it's loaded successfully and rendering a fallback if it is not.

In practice, it could look like the following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.safeSrc = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor();
    var src = ko.unwrap(options.src);
    $('<img />').attr('src', src).on('load', function() {
      $(element).attr('src', src);
    }).on('error', function() {
      $(element).attr('src', ko.unwrap(options.fallback));
    });
  }
};
```

And then, you can apply the binding like this:

```
<img alt="Foo" data-bind="safeSrc: {src: imageObservable, fallback: 'https://example.com/fallback.png'}" />
```

Note that this presumes you're using jQuery - but you can easily rewrite the event listener.

Finally, I would also like to say that you should be rendering a different `src` instead of the background image - unless you have a specific reason to require one?

Either way, you can simply change the line `$(element).attr('src', ko.unwrap(options.fallback));` to `$(element).css('background-image', 'url(' + ko.unwrap(options.fallback) + ')');`.

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Here, you can see it all in action: https://jsfiddle.net/13vkutkv/2/

*(EDIT: I replaced the cheeky hotlink to the Knockout JS logo with Placehold.it)*

P.S.: Depending on how you wish to interact with the element in future (interacting with/updating the binding), you may wish to use `applyBindingsToNode` (i.e. the Knockout-way), rather than manipulating the `src` attribute directly on the DOM element.

Comment: Be careful that the fallback image doesn't fail and trigger the on error, it can end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Very good point. But I have already accounted for that issue: this binding creates a virtual image element for the purpose of checking if it is loaded successfully, rather than using the original DOM element that's passed into the binding. Unless I misunderstood your point.

Comment: Ahh yes, nice solution! I didn't pay that much attn to the code as it looked so similar to something I'd implemented. Might have to pinch that idea for future use.

Comment: No worries. But you're right that this solution doesn't take care of a missing fallback image - let's leave it up to the developer not to fall back on a 404. :)

Answer (score 0):

To show alternate image if img src is not found make alternate image link in your server logic and use only src: 'imagePath' in your front-end

Or if it is important to do it in front-end, you should look at this post:
[Display alternate image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772346/display-alternate-image)

Comment: Good answer, but it would help to add some example code.

Comment: @Roberto ,thanks ,with great pleasure, but i don't know his (her) beck-end(

Answer (score 0):

I always check my images with a deferred object to be sure they will load. This is using the jquery deferred method, but you could use any deferred library. I coded this from memory, so there may be some errors.

```
<img data-bind="attr: {src: $root.imagePath()}, style: { 'background-image': 'url('imagePath')' }" class="img-responsive">

var myController = function()
{
    var self = this;
    this.imagePath = ko.observable('myPath.png'); // Make the image url an observable
    var getImagePath = function(path)
    { 
        var imagePath = this.imagePath();
        isLoaded(imagePath).done(function(result)
        {
            // The image will load fine, do nothing.
        }).fail(function(e)
        {
            self.imagePath('defaultImageOnFail.png'); // replace the image if it fails to load
        });
    };
    getImagePath();
};

var isLoaded = function(img)
{
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var imgObj = $("<img src='"+img+"'/>");
    if(imgObj.height > 0 || imgObj.width > 0)
    {
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }
    else
    {
        imgObj.on("load", function(e)
        {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        });
        imgObj.on("error", function(e)
        {
            console.info("VoteScreenController.isLoaded URL error");
            deferred.reject();
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise();
};
```