# How to modify this php code?

Tags: php

in my opencart I have image in products category page. 
If I have set image in category show in category if I haven't set image show onather one.

```
    <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
  <div class="category-img" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumb; ?>') no-repeat;"></div>
<?php }else{ ?>
  <div class="category-img" style="background: url(image/catalog/category/default-thum.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to modify code.

If I have set image then show image,
else if 
No showing.

Can someone tell me how to modify code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124866/how-does-one-use-the-onerror-attribute-of-an-img-element

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator .Check this code:

```
  <div class="category-img" style="background: url('<?php echo ($thumb ?: 'image/catalog/category/default-thum.jpg'); ?>') 50% 50% no-repeat;"></div>
```

[http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Littel typo you might want to fix