# Hide the broken image if image is not available is database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query in PHP, i don't want to display broken images if the image data is not available in database

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Candidates c1 LEFT JOIN Parties p1 on p1.Id = 
c1.CurrentParty where c1.Id = 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

<div class="candidates">
<h5>Candidates for 2019 Vice-President Elections</h5>
<table class="table-bordered table">
<tr>
<th>Candidate Name</th>
<th>Party Name</th>
<th>Party Symbol</th>
<th>Candidate Image</th>
</tr>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["CandidateName"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["PartyName"]; ?></td>
<td><img src="<?php echo $row["PartySymbol"]; ?>" width="75" height="50" />
</td>
<td><img src="<?php echo $row["Photo"]; ?>" width="75" height="50" /></td>
</tr>
<?php }}?>
</table>
</div>
```

Please help me out! 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onerror` attribute .

```
<img src="<?php echo $row["Photo"]; ?>" width="75" height="50" onerror="this.style.display='none';" />
```

Comment: Nice and simple. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use The Following Code:**

```
<td><?php echo ($row["PartySymbol"] != "")? '<img src='.$row["PartySymbol"].' width="75" height="50" />' : ''; ?> </td>

<td><?php echo ($row["Photo"] != "")? '<img src='.$row["Photo"].' width="75" height="50" />' : ''; ?></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, please try this code. (Assuming my understanding of your problem is correct).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Candidates c1 LEFT JOIN Parties p1 on p1.Id = 
c1.CurrentParty where c1.Id = 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

<div class="candidates">
    <h5>Candidates for 2019 Vice-President Elections</h5>
    <table class="table-bordered table">
        <tr>
            <th>Candidate Name</th>
            <th>Party Name</th>
            <th>Party Symbol</th>
            <th>Candidate Image</th>
        </tr>
<?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) :
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) :
?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $row["CandidateName"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row["PartyName"]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="<?= $row["PartySymbol"]; ?>" width="75" height="50" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if($row["Photo"]): ?>
                            <img src="<?= $row["Photo"]; ?>" width="75" height="50" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<?php 
            endwhile;
        endif;
?>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have improved couple of things, please check them:

1. Instead of using `<?php echo $var; ?>`, please use `<?= $var; ?>`
2. Also, try to avoid `<? if() {` and `<? } ?>`, try to use `<? if ():` and `<? endif; ?>`. It will make the code a lot more easier to read.
3. Also, you can use HTML `onerror` attribute. This will execute JS on fallback if the image is not found at src.

References:

- [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)
- [How does one use the onerror attribute of an img element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124866/how-does-one-use-the-onerror-attribute-of-an-img-element)