# In Angular, how to know if an image came from the API, if not loader another one instead?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

in my code I get an image of the API (row. fotoPessoa), if I don't have an image I put another one in place ([src] = "imgPessoa"). How to do this?

```
          <ng-container matColumnDef="fotoIndividuo">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Foto </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Foto: " > 
              <img [src]="imgPessoa" > 
              {{row.fotoPessoa}} 
            </td>
          </ng-container>
```

Comment: use onerror event

Comment: `[src]="row.fotoPessoa || imgPessoa"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124866/how-does-one-use-the-onerror-attribute-of-an-img-element

Comment: <img [src]="row. fotoPessoa" onerror=this.src = 'imgPessoa';">