# Display a default photo

Tags: c#

I am trying to show an image as a default when no image is selected.

```
var photoContentHtml = "";
if (restService.category === "Photo") {

     photoContentHtml = "<img onerror='this.onerror=null;this.src=\'http://app.org/layerimages/noimage.jpg\'' src='http://app.org/layerimages/{photo}' width='200px' height='150px'>";
}
```

but `onerror` doesn't seem to work. It keeps returning a broken photo. According to what I see in console, it returns a `404` and gets the path `app.org/layerimages/` without the `noimage.jpg`.
If I browse the link, it returns the photo and in the app it shows it like this

[image]

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Update:
No photo uploaded still shows a broken image icon.

[image]

Uploaded photo with no image

[image]

Comment: Did you do a count on the single quotes after `onerror=` ?

Comment: I open a single quote for `onerror`, then a single quote for the `src` and then I close both of them.

Comment: see: [How does one use the onerror attribute of an img element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124866/how-does-one-use-the-onerror-attribute-of-an-img-element)  (which makes this a question about HTML, or JavaScript ?)

Comment: `img onerror='this.onerror=null;this.src=http://app.org/layerimages/noimage.jpg\'` this also doesn't work. I am not sure if it can be done like so, I am converting the whole thing in a string and assigning the value to `photoContentHtml `

Comment: I Think the link says, use: `img onerror="this.src='http://app.org/layerimages/noimage.jpg\';"`

Comment: I get an error saying `;` is expected at `this.src`. I am treating the whole thing as a string and it can't differentiate where the double quotes start as well as end. The same goes for the single quotes. The funny thing it, it shows the photo from this `src='http://app.org/layerimages/{photo}'`

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to use singe- and/or double quotes in HTML:

Expected:

- `1.png` and `2.png` should be present,
- `1error.png` should not be present

```
<img alt="1" src='1.png' >
<hr>
<img alt="2" src="1error.png" onerror="true;this.src='2.png';">
```

Above will show `1.png`, and `2.png` below it.

The same code in C#:

```
String htmlcode = $"<img alt=\"1\" src='1.png' ><hr><img alt=\"2\" src=\"1error.png\" onerror=\"true;this.src='2.png';\">";
```

Comment: This kinda works. If there is image uploaded, it shows both the uploaded image as well as the `noimage.jpg`. if there is no uploaded photo, it shows an icon for a broken photo and shows the `noimage.jpg` below as it can be seen in the updated original question.